# Do identical entropies imply perfect correlation?

Tags: correlation, entropy, information-theory

If two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same Shannon entropy, $$H(X) = H(Y)$$

can it be said that their Pearson correlation $\rho(X,Y) = 1$?

Is it true always or just in some cases, which cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, equality of entropy does not imply unit correlation. Counterexample: two independent normal random variables with equal variances will have equal entropy ($\frac{1}2 \ln(2\pi e\sigma^2)$) but zero correlation. Actually, given two normal random variables with equal variances, their entropies will be equal but their correlation may be anything between $-1$ and $1$.

Intuitively, entropy measures surprise, while correlation measures linear dependence; these are quite different things, so you would not expect a tight relationship between the two.

Comment: Another counter-example: $X$ and $Y$ are discrete categorical and all $X$s are cats and all $Y$s are dogs. Then Shannon entropy is identical but correlation is not even defined..

Comment: @NickCox, if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables (rather than mere random phenomena) as specified in the OP, what does it mean to say that $X$s are cats and $Y$s are dogs?

Comment: I trust that you just need some coding such as 1 : cat, 2: dog to make this more formal. I'm imagining that the cats could have been dogs, and vice versa. Otherwise put, the point of the example is that $X, Y$ constant means identical entropy but undefined correlation.

Comment: @NickCox, got it, thank you.